# How to get title of a columnt in TListView control?

Tags: autoit

All I know is `ControlListView` function: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlListView.htm

and there is an option `GetText` with two parameters for row and column but there I can't see anything to get the text of column heading, that is the place where user can click by mouse and for example sort by that column etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [_GUICtrlListView_GetColumn](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_GUICtrlListView_GetColumn.htm). This function returns an array with information about the given ListView column.

```
Local $aCol = _GUICtrlListView_GetColumn($lvwMsgTable, 0)
ConsoleWrite('Title of column 0: ' & $aCol[5] & @LF)

$aCol = _GUICtrlListView_GetColumn($lvwMsgTable, 1)
ConsoleWrite('Title of column 1: ' & $aCol[5] & @LF)

$aCol = _GUICtrlListView_GetColumn($lvwMsgTable, 2)
ConsoleWrite('Title of column 2: ' & $aCol[5] & @LF)
```

I don't know if this is working with a TListView though.